# How can I get the Plain text AND the HTML of a DOM element created from XML?

Tags: php, xml, dom

We have thousands of Closed Caption XML files that we have to import to a database as plain text, as well as preserve the HTML markup for conversion to another CC format.  I have been able to extract the plain text quite easily, but can't seem to find the correct way of extracting the raw HTML as well.

Is there a way to accomplish something like "`->htmlContent`" in the same way that `->textContent` works below?

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 60)));
$xml = @file_get_contents('http://blah-blah-blah/16TH.xml', 0, $ctx);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$ptags = $dom->getElementsByTagName( "p" );
foreach( $ptags as $p ) {
    $text   = $p->textContent;
}
```

**Typical `<p>` being processed:**

```
<p begin="00:00:14.83" end="00:00:18.83" tts:textAlign="left">
    <metadata ccrow="12" cccol="8"/>
    (male narrator)<br></br> THE 16TH AND 17TH CENTURIES<br></br> WERE THE FORMATIVE 200 YEARS
</p>
```

**Successful `->textContent` Result**

```
(male narrator) THE 16TH AND 17TH CENTURIES WERE THE FORMATIVE 200 YEARS
```

***Desired* HTML Result**

```
(male narrator)<br></br> THE 16TH AND 17TH CENTURIES<br></br> WERE THE FORMATIVE 200 YEARS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other word you would like to save specific nodes - `br` elements and text nodes. You can do this with DOM+Xpath:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->loadXml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//p') as $p) {
  $content = '';
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('.//br|.//text()', $p) as $node) {
    $content .= $document->saveHtml($node);
  }
  var_dump($content);
}
```

Output:

```
string(86) "
    (male narrator)<br> THE 16TH AND 17TH CENTURIES<br> WERE THE FORMATIVE 200 YEARS
"
```

### The Xpath Expression

Any descendant `br`: `.//br`
Any descendant text node: `.//text()`
Combined expression: `.//br|.//text()`

### Namespaces

If you XML uses namespaces you have to register and use them.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->loadXml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('tt', 'http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//tt:p') as $p) {
  $content = '';
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('.//tt:br|.//text()', $p) as $node) {
    $content .= $document->saveHtml($node);
  }
  var_dump($content);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and the `foreach` loop is missed completely, having nothing to loop through.  Is that because `$document->loadXml($html)` is expecting HTML code?  The file being processed is XML, not HTML.  You can try it with http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/streamingassets/16TH/16TH-001-01.xml

Comment: No, it expects XML, `$html` is just a variable. It can be an namespace issue. Look for an "xmlns=" attribute. If a default namespace is used (XHTML?) You need to register a prefix for it an use it.

Comment: Okay...you lost me with the namespace/register prefix part. Does the link in my last comment qualify for that, and if so how do I modify your answer for it.

Comment: Yes it does. The XML is a format called Timed Text (TT) Authoring Format. The namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1`. Open the source view and check out the document element.

Comment: Saw that, and have been googling it, but alas, all of this is out of my wheelhouse, so I'm lost as to how that needs to affect the code you supplied.

Comment: I already added a section to the answer before I posted the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the forest for the trees...quite a simple solution after I realized that `strip_tags()` was failing because of the closing tags of the `BR` tag:

```
foreach( $ptags as $p ) {
    $text = $p->textContent;
    $html = $p->ownerDocument->saveXML($p);         // Raw HTML
    $html = str_ireplace('<br></br>','<br>',$html); // Cleanup the BR usage
    $html = strip_tags($html,'<br>');               // Strip the tags I don't need
}
```

There's likely a more elegent solution with the DOM, or with regex, but this did get it done.

Comment: There is a method `saveHTML($p)` you could use instead of `saveXML`, that might save you the replace call.